# Let $L/F$ be Galois with Galois group $G$, and let $K$ be a subfield corresponding to the subgroup $H$. Then $N_{G}(H)=\{\sigma\in G:\sigma K=K\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I am a bit confused about this exercise. Is there someone who can help?

The exercise is

Let $L/F$ be a Galois extension with Galois group $G$, and let $K$ be an intermediate field corresponding to the subgroup $H$ of $G$. Show that the normalizer $N_{G}(H)$ consists of those $\sigma \in G$ for which $\sigma K=K$.

A hint is given which is: To say that $\sigma K=K$ is the same as saying that $\sigma \alpha \in K$ for every $\alpha \in K$.

I know that I have to show $N_G(H)=\{\sigma\in G \mid \sigma\cdot K=K\}$. Which is the same as showing $\sigma \alpha \in K \iff \sigma h \sigma^{-1}
=h.$

But I don't understand how I should do that.

Answer (score 3):

Let $N=N_G(H)=\{g\in G| \ gH=Hg\}$ and $T=\{g\in G|\ gK=K\}$

- We show that $T\subseteq N$:

Let $g\in T, h\in H,\ x\in K=L^H$. Then $ghg^{-1}(x)=g(hg^{-1}(x))$ and since $gK=K$ it is $g^{-1}(x)\in K$ and $hg^{-1}(x)=g^{-1}(x)$ since $h\in H$ and $K=L^H$. Then $ghg^{-1}(x)=gg^{-1}(x)=x$ hence
$g\in N$

- We show that $N\subseteq T$:

Let $n\in N, g'\in H,x\in K=L^H$. Then $g'n(x)=n[n^{-1}g'n](x)$. Since $N=N_G(H)$  it is $n^{-1}g'n\in H$ thus $ng'n^{-1}(x)=x$ so $g'n(x)=n(x)$ so $n(x)$ is in the subfield fixed by $H$ which is $K$.  Hence $n \in T$

Comment: When you show T\subseteq N. Then I don't understand what you mean by $K=L^H$, what is $L^H$. And how do you get that $hg^{-1}(x)=g^{-1}(x)$. 

And how do you get that $g\in N$, just because you have shown that $ghg^{-1}(x)=x$

Comment: $L^H$ is the set of element of $L$ fixed by $H$

Comment: Okay, thank you, I'll look at it again now. Is it okay that I ask you again, if I still don't understand it?

Comment: Yes of course it is ok!

Comment: How do we know that $K=L^H$? And I still don't get how we have that $hg^{-1}(x)=g^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: You say that $K$ is the subfield corresponding to $H$ which is the same as what I say.

Comment: So the reason behind $hg^{-1}(x)=g^{-1}(x)$ is that $h\in H$ fix $g^{-1}(x)\in K$?

Comment: @Hello Yes exactly

Comment: But isn't h supposed to be an automorphism of H then? How do we know that it is that?

Comment: $h$ is an element of $H$. What do you mean by "an automorphism of $H$"?

Comment: I meant automorphism of K

Comment: Yes it is but how is this related with everything else?

Comment: Because in my textbook there is a definition which says that h fix an element $g^{-1}(x)$ if $hg^{-1}(x)$, for a h which is an automorphism of K. So I thought to be able to say  $hg^{-1}(x)=g^{-1}(x)$, we need to have that h is an automorphism of K, which I was not so sure how we could see.

Comment: we know that $h\in H$ and this is enough to say that $h$ stabilizes every element of $L^H$

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but I don't understand why we have that $g\in N$, because $ghg^{-1}(x)=x$?

Comment: since $ghg^{-1}=Id\Rightarrow gh\in Hg \Rightarrow gH\subseteq Hg\Rightarrow gH=Hg\Rightarrow g\in N$

Comment: Why do we have $ghg^{-1}=Id\Rightarrow gh\in Hg$,and then I get that $gH\subseteq Hg$, but for $gH=Hg$ to hold we have to have that $Hg\subseteq gH$, and how do we know that?

Comment: In the seccond part where you show $N\subseteq T$, I get that $n^{-1}g'n\in H$, because we have that $n^{-1}g'n=g'\in H$, but then I don't get how you then get $ng'n^{-1}(x)=x$, and then after that get $g'n(x)=n(x)$, and how you from there then say that $n\in T$

Comment: I have tried to look at it again, and in the second part where you show $N \in subseteq T$ I still don't understand $ng'n^{-1}(x)=x$ but I realize if $ng'n^{-1}(x)=x$ then $ng'n^{-1}(x)=Id$ which might imply that $ng'(x)=n(x)$ but then I don't understand how you get $g'n(x)=n(x)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113604/discussion-between-hello-and--).

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $N_G(H)=N=\{\tau\in G\mid \tau H=H\tau\}$. Let $\tau\in N,\sigma\in H$ and $\alpha\in K$. To show $\tau(\alpha)\in K$, it suffices to show that $\sigma(\tau(\alpha))=\tau(\alpha)$. Now by hypothesis, $\sigma\tau=\tau\tilde\sigma$ for some $\tilde\sigma\in H$. Thus $$\tau(\alpha)=\tau(\tilde\sigma(\alpha))=\sigma(\tau(\alpha)).$$

Comment: But why do you look at \tau \in G? Aren't we supposed to look  at \sigma\in G

Comment: The only reason I started out with $\tau$ was that it only has three letters to type. Don't worry too much about it. Can you follow the argument? If there's any problem, please let me know.

Comment: So when you write \tau, you mean \sigma?

Comment: No. $\tau$ is just an arbitrary element of $N_G(H)$. Similarly, $\sigma$ is an arbitrary element of $H$.

Comment: But we have that $\sigma \in G$?

Comment: and you write $\sigma \in H$, why?

Comment: And why do you look at 
$N=\{\tau\in G| \tau H=H\tau\}$, when we're talking about $\{\sigma\in G |\sigma K=K\}$?

Comment: and where do you get $\sigma \tau=\tau \tilde \sigma$ from?

and how do yo get $\tau(\alpha)=\tau(\tilde \sigma(\alpha))$